# Build dynamic query according to variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, plsql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I am facing problem while fetching records from database in Role Based Access.

I have a Table let us say `TableA`. I have 5 Columns in it i.e, `ID (primary key), FirstName, LastName, RegistrationNumber, EmployeeIdent`.

All the columns `except ID` are of `Varchar` type.

I have a stored procedure to search the records. I am passing string to it and finding matching records from all five columns.

Now, the problem I am facing is in Role Based Access.

The requirement is when user is of "`Admin`" type then find matching records from all five columns but when is of "`naive`" user type then search matching records from only ID column.

I have passed the variable @`userType` to stored procedure from which I can determine the user type.

One way to resolve this problem is If Condition. Like `if (@userType) = 'Admin'` then some query `Else` Some other. 
But I don't want to write query in If Condition.

Another way to resolve this is to store query in `varchar` type of variable and then execute is using `EXEC ()`, but I have heard that it creates more overhead on server (I am not sure about it).

So any other way to fulfill this requirement?

The query to search records is

```
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(MAX)= '' 

SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
WHERE 
Convert(varchar,ID) LIKE CASE WHEN LEN(@SearchText) = 0 THEN Convert(varchar,ID) ELSE '%'+ ISNULL(@SearchText,'0') + '%' END OR
FirstName LIKE CASE WHEN LEN(@SearchText) = 0 THEN FirstName ELSE '%'+ ISNULL(@SearchText,'') + '%' END OR
LastName LIKE CASE WHEN LEN(@SearchText) = 0 THEN LastName ELSE '%'+ ISNULL(@SearchText,'') + '%' END OR
RegistrationNumber LIKE CASE WHEN LEN(@SearchText) = 0 THEN RegistrationNumber ELSE '%'+ ISNULL(@SearchText,'') + '%' END OR
EmployeeIdent LIKE CASE WHEN LEN(@SearchText) = 0 THEN EmployeeIdent ELSE '%'+ ISNULL(@SearchText,'') + '%' END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
*
FROM TABLEA
WHERE
(@userType = 'admin'
--add any other criteria for admin type here
) or (
@userType = 'naive'
--add any other criteria for naive type here
)
```

Comment: Can you make this for query I have added in my question?